# How to serialize an object to a raw XML

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization

**Background** :
I am working on this integration solution where I have to implement a WCF service (BizTalk) with a custom fault contract. The fault message should look like follows,

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode>002</faultcode>
         <faultstring>some fault</faultstring>
         <detail>
               <wor:invalidMessageFault xmlns:wor="somenamespace">
                  <faultCode>002</faultCode>
                  <faultReference>Client WebService</faultReference>
                  <faultText>some fault</faultText>
               </wor:invalidMessageFault>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**So far:** I have created a custom fault inspector to intercept the fault message and send back the fault.

**Problem :** I need to construct the `<detail>` section of the fault message and as far as I figured out only way to do it is to dump raw xml into it, because in the fault message construction,

```
var faultException = new FaultException<RawXMLString>(raw, fault.faultText, new FaultCode(fault.faultCode)).CreateMessageFault();
```

It only accept an object (which can be serialized) as detail, and I tried different things but I could construct the same message with object.

Finally I thought of using a custom serialization to generate the exact message,

```
public class RawXMLString : IXmlSerializable
{
    private string xmlTemplate = @"<wor:invalidMessageFault xmlns:wor="some namespace">
          <faultCode>{0}</faultCode>
          <faultReference>Client WebService</faultReference>
          <faultText>{1}</faultText>
        </wor:invalidMessageFault>";

    public string FaultCode { get; set; }

    public string FaultText { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteRaw(string.Format(xmlTemplate,FaultCode,FaultText));
    }
}
```

Now there is another issue, because I don't want `<RawXMLString>` tag, is there any way to force serializer to ignore the root?

Comment: Are you set on using a custom serializer? You could easily construct this message with a simple XDocument declaration.

Comment: Are you suggesting passing the XDocument into the FaultException? I do not have control over serializer as the serialization is done by WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit the bill?

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "somenamespace",
 ElementName = "invalidMessageFault")]
public class InvalidMessageFault : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string FaultCode { get; set; }

    public string FaultText { get; set; }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("faultCode", FaultCode);
        writer.WriteElementString("faultReference", "Client WebService");
        writer.WriteElementString("faultText", FaultText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost... but missing namespace prefix, and I do not have access to the serializer as the fault message is serialized by the WCF, and that's the reason I was using the IXmlSerializable

Comment: Does that make any difference? (the output is semantically equivalent)

Comment: Issue is that the supplier who want us to implement this interface is adamant about it, not sure how they parse the message.

Comment: Is there a way of approaching this differently? The issue with this method is that the root node has already been written by the time IXmlSerializable is called, and the only control you have is via [XmlRoot] which does not allow a prefix to be specified. Is there something you can do in your fault inspector to modify the response (or generate one from scratch)?

Comment: I managed to do it, but I wouldn't say it's the cleanest way, but I managed to construct the XMLNode and passed it in to the Fault like new FaultException<XMLNode>(... and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
[XmlRoot("wor:invalidMessageFault xmlns:wor=\"some namespace\"")]
public class RawXMLString : IXmlSerializable
{
    private string xmlTemplate = @"<faultCode>{0}</faultCode>
      <faultReference>Client WebService</faultReference>
      <faultText>{1}</faultText>";

    public string FaultCode { get; set; }

    public string FaultText { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteRaw(string.Format(xmlTemplate,FaultCode,FaultText));
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives incorrect root node <wor_x003A_invalidMessageFault_x0020_xmlns_x003A_wor_x003D__x0022_....>

Comment: I gave you a starting point, you need to set your typename and namespace

Comment: I tried this approach, with tweaking the attributes before posting the question, but there is no way I can set the namespace prefix with this, unless I use a custom serializer.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1313052.aspx?How+do+I+set+the+namespace+prefix+for+the+root+element

Comment: Yes.. but for that to work I need to have access to XmlSerializer, which I don't in this scenario.