# wcf fault exception namespace prefix

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am working on WCF service with a custom fault contract.
I need to construct the  section with Namespace and Prefix like below

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
   <s:Fault>
    <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Some Fault</faultstring>
    <detail>
       <wor:invalidMessageFault xmlns:wor="somenamespace">
        <faultCode>001</faultCode>
        <faultText>some fault</faultText>
        <faultReference>12345</faultReference>
       </wor:invalidMessageFault>
    </detail>
   </s:Fault>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So far, I can manage to construct custom fault without Prefix.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
   <s:Fault>
    <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Some Fault</faultstring>
    <detail>
       <invalidMessageFault xmlns="somenamespace">
        <faultCode>001</faultCode>
        <faultText>some fault</faultText>
        <faultReference>12345</faultReference>
       </invalidMessageFault>
    </detail>
   </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I don't have access to serializer as fault message. it is serialized by WCF.
I can not pass XDocument to Fault Exception.

Found same quesiton here but couldn't find the result.
 [How to serialize an object to a raw XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29157164/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-a-raw-xml)
How can I manage to construct the XML Node to passed into the Fault? Is there any way I can construct namespace prefix in Fault Exception detail?

Comment: Why? The two are semantically the same. No sane XML deserialiser should care about a difference in namespace prefixes.

Comment: Yes, Thats my understanding too. However, issue is that the supplier who want us to implement this interface is adamant. They are using SAP and I am not sure how they parse the message.